# Automatically open both Google Map and Streetview

Tags: javascript, r, google-maps, shiny, googleway

I'm wondering if someone better than I am at R Shiny could tell me if the following is possible (it may not be, but I'd like to know if not).

**Question: Can I open both a google map and interactive streetview in Shiny?**

Why I want to do this:

I have a programmed google map coming from the googleway package shiny integration. It looks as below (code at the bottom):
[image]

In my shiny app, I can click and drag the streetview guy in the from the icon in the corner:

[image]

Resulting in the streetview:
[image]

**I'd like to jump straight into this street view on an action button or tab click instead of making the user do the drag and drop process, so that I can have the map in one shiny tab and directly into the interactive streetview in another tab, or better yet have the map and streetview side by side as in (link here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple).**

**Is there a way to do this?**

I am also looking into googleway package to see if there is another way, but as far as I can tell I can get into an interactive panorama but not street view directly. I am also looking into the possibility of using the html integration in shiny to go directly into Street View service.

Code (simplified, but tested):

```
library(googleway)
library(shiny)

gpscoordlat <- 39.647806
gpscoordlon <- -104.940230
markerpointsplace <- data.frame(
  lat=c(gpscoordlat),
  lon=c(gpscoordlon)
)

ui <- fluidPage(google_mapOutput("map"))


server <- function(input, output, session){

 ###Use Your API key here###
  api_key <- "GoogleAPIKeyHere"


  output$map <- renderGoogle_map({
    google_map(location=c(gpscoordlat, gpscoordlon), key= api_key, zoom=15) %>%
      add_markers(data=markerpointsplace , update_map_view= FALSE)

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The 'split view' is on my [todo list](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/76)... I'll get to it eventually, but at the moment I don't know of an easy way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @SymbolixAU, so I'm obviously using your package a bunch (once again, thank you, awesome work). Great that it's on the list, I'll post it on the github issues if I find a workaround.

Comment: I've moved the functionality into the master brach of my project; I'm happy it's working as intended. Is this the sort of thing you were thinking about?

Comment: Based on the answer below yes! I'm taking a look and testing through now. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Caution

This functionality is currently under development. Progress can be tracked [directly on github](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/136), but I will endeavour to update this post as I go along.

You can install the development version using

```
devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
```

---

### Example

Here's an example of two maps, both controlled by the same street-view 'pegman'.

Note the two UI outputs, the standard `map` output, and another one I've called `pano`. This `pano` is then used in the `split_view` argument to `google_map()`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googleway)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = 6,
      google_mapOutput(outputId = "map")
    ),
    box(width = 6,
        google_mapOutput(outputId = "pano")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set_key("map_api_key")

  output$map <- renderGoogle_map({
    google_map(location = c(-37.817386, 144.967463), 
             zoom = 12, 
             split_view = "pano")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

#### Notes

- if your initial location doesn't fall directly on a valid 'street view' location, the streetview page will be blank

Comment: So this is pretty awesome. Works great for the addresses I have tested so far (which get geocoded via googleway too). Is there a way to include the fullscreen option available at (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple)? I.e. fullscreen_control= TRUE ? Seriously no worries if not, this is great! I also modified the question to make it more relevant for users looking for this functionality (to make it more applicable with the updated title). Thanks again!

Comment: @NealBarsch - those other options should be possible. Just need to figure out how to work them in. And I hope you don't mind the question title edit - I thought I would make it better reflect the requirement (and more 'searchable')

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to make this easier to find for people looking to do this, and it answered what I wanted to do anyhow. Least I can do for how much I use googleway (literally every day). Is there a spot you can recommend for learning how to program the Java widgets you code in googleway? It seems extremely useful and I'm in the process of learning Java anyhow, anywhere but the htmlwidgets package guide? I've been using the googleway code as examples, I learn stuff better looking at examples.

Comment: Also, if I'm not getting too greedy, a function suggestion that I would use (and others might) would be the heading function that exists in the browser google_map_pano function. Intention in my case would be to open the streetview looking at the address inputted. But this is great already, so that is simply a suggestion.

Comment: @NealBarsch I learnt pretty much everything from reading timelyportfolio's ['build a widget a week' project](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/buildingwidgets), and the [leaflet source code](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet). You'll notice I've used a lot of their structures. Like you I learn best by working through other people's examples.

Comment: @NealBarsch and could you add any suggestions / feature requests to the [issues page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues) - it helps me keep track and prioritise them.

Comment: Yeah I've been going through the leaflet code quite a bit as well. Another tab in the app I'm building using your code above as one of the tabs uses leaflet to map and plot crime data. And will do on the issues page, thanks again!