# disable zoom, dragging in gvisMap

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis, rgooglemaps, plotgooglemaps

Is there a way to entirely disable dragging and/or zooming in gvisMap, and remove the zoom control also?  I have looked at options under [google.com developers docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#Configuration_Options) referenced in the help for `gvisMap(options)` but can't see this control.

Broadening the scope of the question to include alternative packages, I note that `plotGoogleMaps()` in R package `plotGoogleMaps` has an option `draggable=FALSE`, but there is no corresponding parameter to disable zoom, and rendering it in shiny is not so simple as `renderGvis()`.  I had a quick look at `RgoogleMaps` package also.

Background: I particularly want a google satellite map for the transition to street view, I set the map bounds from a zoom/drag enabled leaflet map, so enabling zoom/drag on the google satellite view is redundant/confusing.  Disabling these capabilities is a detail that would improve the UX.

[edit] This revised example is a bit longer but shows in full the functionality I am referring to.  It works fine apart from some niggles such as I don't know why the fudge factors are needed, and I don't know how to turn off the markers in the google map - but these are outside the scope of my question.  The specific subject of my question however is: can I disable drag and zoom on the google map, just like I do in `leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE, dragging = F)`?  If I had a supplementary question, it would be something like 'how do I reduce the proliferation of google mapping packages?' - but that is not a valid question for this forum.  That said, I'd welcome any broader steer on how to simplify this.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(googleVis)
library(RgoogleMaps)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidPage(fluidRow(
  h5('control map - use only this one to drag and zoom'),
  column(6, leafletOutput('controlmap'), offset = 0)
  ,
  h5("google map - drop 'peg man' to get street view"),
  column(6, htmlOutput('gmap'), offset = 0)
)
,
fluidRow(
  h5('choropleth - where the colour-coded data is displayed'),
  column(6, leafletOutput('fitmap'), offset = 0)
)))

server <- function(input, output) {
  latlongR <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$controlmap_bounds)) {
      data.frame(
        Lat = c(51.52, 51.51),
        Long = c(-.106, -.096),
        Tip = as.character(1:2)
      )
    } else {
      data.frame(
        Lat = c(
          input$controlmap_bounds$north,
          input$controlmap_bounds$south
        ),
        Long = c(
          input$controlmap_bounds$east,
          input$controlmap_bounds$west
        ),
        Tip = as.character(1:2)
      )
    }
  })

  boundR <- reactive({
    fudgezoom <- .7 #fudge - unsure why neeed
    x0 <- latlongR()
    d1 <- abs(diff(x0[, 1]))
    d2 <- abs(diff(x0[, 2]))
    m1 <- mean(x0[, 1])
    m2 <- mean(x0[, 2])
    x1 <- c(m1 + fudgezoom * d1 / 2, m1 - fudgezoom * d1 / 2)
    x2 <- c(m2 + fudgezoom * d2 / 2, m2 - fudgezoom * d2 / 2)
    x3 <- cbind(x0, LatLong = paste0(x1, ':', x2))
    x3
  })

  output$controlmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(width = 500, height = 400) %>%
      addProviderTiles('OpenStreetMap') %>%
      setView(lng = -0.106831,
              lat = 51.515328,
              zoom = 15)
  })

  output$fitmap <- renderLeaflet({
    x1 <- latlongR()
    fudgefit <- .5 #this fudge depends on layout and maybe other variables
    x2 <-
      RgoogleMaps::MaxZoom(
        latrange = fudgefit * x1$Lat,
        lonrange = fudgefit * x1$Long,
        size = c(500, 400)
      )
    leaflet(
      width = 500,
      height = 400,
      options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE, dragging = F)
    ) %>%
      addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
      fitBounds(
        lng1 = x1$Long[1],
        lat1 = x1$Lat[1],
        lng2 = x1$Long[2],
        lat2 = x1$Lat[2]
      ) %>%
      setView(zoom = x2,
              lat = mean(x1$Lat),
              lng = mean(x1$Long))
  })

  output$gmap <- renderGvis({
    x3 <- boundR()
    gvisMap(
      x3,
      "LatLong" ,
      tipvar = "Tip",
      options = list(
        showTip = F,
        icons = NULL,
        useZoomControl = F,
        useMapTypeControl = F
      )
    )

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example with code please

Comment: perhaps something [like this - open both google maps and streetview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48901711/5977215), or [like this - access streetview from R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39198783/5977215) are of use?

Comment: Awesome - most relevant.  I must study.

Comment: googleway package from SymbolixAU is impressive.  I modified my example code to fully show what I am up to and what I am trying to achieve, which currently means 3 maps, top left being the 'input' for drag/zoom, the other two 'outputs' for data and image.  I want to disable any zoom/drag input from the 'output' google map.  Hope that's clearer.